# eBay Digital Signatures for APIs Signature header error 215114 The create time of signature parameters is not in right range

Tags: digital-signature

I am trying to test Digital Signatures for APIs and I'm having trouble with the signature header (https://developer.ebay.com/develop/guides/digital-signatures-for-apis#sig). In this example, I am using Excel VBA:

```
http.setRequestHeader "x-ebay-signature-key", jwe
http.setRequestHeader "signature", privateKey
http.setRequestHeader "signature-input", "sig1=(""x-ebay-signature-key"" ""@method"" ""@path"" ""@authority"");created=1666253648295"
```

jwe, privateKey and created time were acquired using the Management API createSigningKey call. I have noted that the creationTime in the API response has 13 digits instead of 10 like in the eBay example.

I receive the following response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorId": 215114,
      "domain": "ACCESS",
      "category": "REQUEST",
      "message": "The create time of signature parameters is not in right range",
      "longMessage": "The create time of signature parameters is not in right range to fulfill the request."
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried using the 13 digit and 10 digits of the Unix timestamp, but get the same error with both. I presume that I am missing something, but am not sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unix timestamp function I was using did not take into account daylight saving time in UK, so was 1 hour in the future. Having corrected this the timestamp is accepted.